# Heating a ball tied to a string so that its potential energy decreases as Center of mass goes down

Tags: thermodynamics, potential, potential-energy

Suppose I have a ball hanging from a thread and I start heating it. The ball is tied from the upper end and as the ball starts to heat it expands and ultimately its centre of mass which is the centre of the sphere goes down.

Due to this its potential energy should also decrease where does this  energy go ??

Also consider what if it is placed on a ground and I start heating it. Now the centre of mass of the ball goes up and thus its potential energy increases.

Now where is this potential energy coming from ??

Answer (score 0):

In a few words: the variation of potential energy is exchanged with heat.

When you heat an object, the heat goes into the vibrations of its molecules. The vibrations have two energy contributions: kinetic energy and potential energy (the elastic energy of the interaction between a molecule and the surrounding ones). This second term slightly depends on the forces applied to the solid. For example, when the ball is suspended, the molecules are slightly stretched in vertical direction.

The result is that heating the suspended ball requires slightly less energy than heating
the ball lying on the surface. In absence of gravity, you need a quantity of heat between the two.